# There is a problem with displaying images when it is called from the Database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

The AppServ Open Project - 8.6.0 for Windows
Now you running on PHP 5.6.30

The problem is that all data and data are being called, but the problem is that the image is not being called

[image: The problem is that all data and data are being called, but the problem is that the image is not being called]

[image: And here is a picture from Database]

*****--my items--*****

```
    <div class="items_parent">
    @if(count($data)>0)
    @foreach($data as $i)
<!-- start item div  -->
        <div  class="item_part">
            <img src="{{asset('storage/'.$i->image_url)}}"
            width="200" height="200"/>
            <b id="price">EGP.{{$i->price}}</b>
            <b id="name">{{$i->name}}</b>
            <b id="unit">{{$i->unit}}</b>
            <p id="desc">{{$i->short_desc}} </p>

            <a href="s_edit_item">{{__("lang.update_s")}}</a>
            {!! Form::open(['url' => 'all_items','files'=>true]) !!}

            {{Form::hidden('i_id',$i->id,[])}}
            {{Form::submit('Edit',['id'=>'btn_detail'])}}


            {{Form::submit(__("lang.delete_btn"),['id'=>'btn_detail'])}}

            {!! Form::close() !!}

        </div>
<!--  end of item div-->
@endforeach
    @endif
    </div>
```

*****--supplier code--*****
//Here is the code for adding products

```
 public function add_item(Request $req){
      $req->validate([

        'i_name'=>'required',
        'i_price'=>'required',
        'i_size'=>'required',
        'i_unit'=>'required',
        'i_cat'=>'required',
        'i_short'=>'required',
        'i_full'=>'required',
        'i_photo'=>'required'
      ]);
      $i=new item;
     $email=$req->session()->get('supplier');
     $i->supplier=$email;
     $i->name=$req->input('i_name');
      $i->price=$req->input('i_price');
      $i->size=$req->input('i_size');
      $i->unit=$req->input('i_unit');
      $i->category=$req->input('i_cat');
      $i->short_desc=$req->input('i_short');
      $i->full_desc=$req->input('i_full');
      $i->image_url=$req->file('i_photo')->store('items_photo','public'); //fule upload= store
      $i->save(); //insert

      return redirect('s_setting'); 
      }
```

Comment: **the problem is that the image is not being called** : Is it true that some images can be displayed (but not all images are displayed) ?

Comment: The pictures that appear are pictures of products that I have added for a long time, but in the case of adding any new products, the pictures do not appear

Comment: Please check whether the `items_photo` directory is **write-permitted** (because if it is **not**, then newly uploaded photos cannot be saved (written) to the system)

Comment: I think the error is in the path to save the images          http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/storage/items_photo/9F4SMYPfYhdxuYf3DKKcyyaM0KVSK5Jpvoyl9sLV.jpeg

Comment: if you think so then fix the code to use the real path

Comment: I fixed it but it wasn't the problem